# Como rodar cron job no servidor

Tags: php, cron

Como faço para rodar um arquivo .php no servidor inteiro, quero rodar um php que mostra o Uptime do server, mas não sei aonde colocar para ver quanto tempo o servidor está ativo. Uso Servidor Dedicado.

Answer (score 4):

Para rodar um script php pelo cron você usa o seguinte comando:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null http://dominio/pasta/script.php
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui!