# Cron Job - Não funciona

Tags: php, cron

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aaa/core/database/connect.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aaa/functions/general.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aaa/functions/users.php';

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users`") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $inc_per_min = income_per_minute($user_id);

        if ($inc_per_min > 0) {
            $conn->query("UPDATE `game_data` SET `money_hand` = `money_hand` + '$inc_per_min' WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }
?>
```

Esse é o código que quero executar todos os minutos.
isto é o que tenho no comando da cron:

```
Current Cron Jobs
Minuto  Hora    Dia Mês Dia útil    Comando Ações
*   *   *   *   *   /home/MyUserName/public_html/aaa/cron_stack.php
```

Alguém me sabe dizer porque não funciona?

Comment: Não funciona por não estar chamando o executável do PHP para interpretar o script.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocar na *cron* o comando como você o executaria na linha de comando.

Se o executável é um script PHP, portanto você o executaria assim:

```
php /home/MyUserName/public_html/aaa/cron_stack.php
```

Logo, na *cron*, ficaria assim:

```
*   *   *   *   *   php /home/MyUserName/public_html/aaa/cron_stack.php
```

Comment: Pois mas o script parece não rodar com esse comando na cron..

Answer (score -1):

curl -s -o /dev/null http://dominio/pasta/script.php

Era só isso... Obrigado APS pela resposta no tópico: [Como rodar cron job no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17185/como-rodar-cron-job-no-servidor?rq=1)

Comment: Esse comando servia aos propósitos da outra pergunta – é para baixar um arquivo remoto.

Comment: Fazer uma requisição web para executar um PHP local não é exatamente o que eu chamaria de uma solução técnica. Há **raros** casos em que é necessário, esse não me parece ser um deles.