# Enviar email uma vez por dia

Tags: php, phpmailer

Boa Tarde,
Como eu faço para enviar email uma vez por dia. Eu utilizo o phpmailer.
Eu tentei usar o while, porém não sei que função determina a quantidade de a cada 24 horas.

meu código:

```html
$assunto = "[RemocenteR] Nova Tarefa Cadastrada!";
    $mensagem = "Prezado usuário, foi enviada uma tarefa pelo sistema remocenter para você. Acesse o menu e verique as tarefas pendentes";
    $dadosDaTarefa = '<br><br>';
    $dadosDaTarefa .= '<strong>Dados da Tarefa</strong>';
    $dadosDaTarefa .= '<br>';
    if($TA_TAREFA != ""){
      $dadosDaTarefa .= 'Tarefa: ' . $TA_TAREFA;
      $dadosDaTarefa .= '<br>';
    }
    if($TA_DESCRICAO != ""){
      $dadosDaTarefa .= 'Descrição: ' . $TA_DESCRICAO;
      $dadosDaTarefa .= '<br>';
    }
    if($TA_PRAZO != ""){
      $dadosDaTarefa .= 'Prazo: ' . $TA_PRAZO_BR;
      $dadosDaTarefa .= '<br>';
    }
    if($TA_PRIORIDADE != ""){
      $dadosDaTarefa .= 'Prioridade: ' .$TA_PRIORIDADE;
      $dadosDaTarefa .= '<br>';
    }
    if($TA_SOLICITANTE != ""){
      $dadosDaTarefa .= 'Soliciante: '. $TA_SOLICITANTE;
      $mensagem .= $dadosDaTarefa;
    }
    $mensagem .= '<br><br>';
    $mensagem .= 'Mensagem gerada automaticamente pelo Sistema!';
    

    if(sendMail('tarefas@remocenter.com.br',$FET_USUARIO['US_EMAIL'], $mensagem, $assunto)){
     echo '<script language = "javascript">alert("Tarefa registrada, foi enviado um e-mail para notificar o  solicitado!")</script>';
    }
    echo ("<script language='javascript'>location.href='tarefas.php'</script>");
  }
```

Obrigada pela força

Comment: Já ouviu falar de Cron Job? Acho que será a melhor saída.

Comment: Sim, só que é um sistema de tarefas web que eu tenho, e digamos que enquanto a tarefa nao for concluida ele envia um email por dia, lembrando o usuario para finalizar a tarefa. Teria como fazer essa comunicação do cronjob com o meu sistema web ?. Obrigada

Comment: Sim, criar um cronjob pra fazer uma requisição curl pra sua api web que inicializa o script de envio de email diário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que está tentando fazer não irá funcionar. PHP é diferente de outras linguagens que fica rodando de forma intermitente no servidor. Ele possui um ciclo de começo, meio e fim. E o fim é o fim mesmo.

Para resolver o seu problema, você pode utilizar CronJobs (Linux) ou o Agendador de tarefas (windows).

A definição é simples: agende a execução diária do seu script. Pode ser programado para rodar a cada 24 horas ou em outros intervalos.

Sendo assim, a cada 24 horas o seu script será chamado e enviará os emails.

Para Cron, pode olhar no link abaixo:
[Como rodar cron job no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17185/como-rodar-cron-job-no-servidor)

Cron (ambientes Linux):

```
1 2 3 4 5 /root/script.php
```

Para o agendador de tarefas, pode utilizar o link abaixo:
[Executar script PHP no agendador de tarefas do Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129554/executar-script-php-no-agendador-de-tarefas-do-windows/)

Agendador de tarefas (Task Scheduler - ambientes Windows):

```
c:/caminhocorreto/php [ -f ] c:/caminho/para/o/script.php
```

Além do que, o Agendador de Tarefas é visual.

Comment: Obrigada. Vou tentar

Answer (score 2):

Para isso voce deve utilizar CRON.

**O que são as Cron Jobs?**

As Cron Jobs são como as Terefas Agendadas do Windows: são tarefas executadas automaticamente de X em X tempos… Fazendo uma analogia à vida real é quando você tira o lixo pra fora ou arruma seu quarto, provavelmente você faz isso seguindo sempre um mesmo intervalo de tempo… De 2 em 2 dias, de 1 em 1 semana e por ai vai.

**Como criar uma Cron Job?**

Se o seu site roda em algum servidor especializado e você tem um painel de controle como o cPanel recomendo que dê uma olhada lá pois existe uma interface web prontinha para gerenciar as crons… se você não tem esse painel ou não tem acesso à ele vai ter que ir direto ao shell / terminal do seu servidor e começar a gastar o dedo.
A definição de uma cron job consiste em uma linha com 6 valores separados por espaço, assim:

```
minuto hora dia mes dia-da-semana linha-de-comando
```

Vamos a alguns exemplos de configuração de tempo antes de criar a cron em si:

**Cron Job que rode todo dia as 06:00am**

```
0 6 * * * linha-de-comando
```

[Referencia](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/o-que-sao-e-como-usar-as-cron-jobs)